# HP Code Wars Check digit algorithm error

Tags: c, windows, algorithm

QUESTION:
http://www.hpcodewars.org/past/cw17/problems/Prob02--CheckDigit.pdf

Here's my code:

```
    int checkdigit(){

    int n,i,j,sum1,sum2,k;

    char ch;
    printf("Enter the number of lines.Then enter ther the codes!");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    char *codes[n];
    int msum[n];
    int fsum[n];
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
        scanf("%s",codes[i]);
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;++i){
            for(j=0,k=3;j<21;j+=3,k+=3){
        char *num;
        num=codes[i];
        ch=num[j];
        sum1+=atoi(ch);
        if(k<21)
        ch=num[k];
        sum2+=atoi(ch);
    }
    msum[i]=sum1*3;
    fsum[i]=((msum[i]+sum2)%10);
    if(fsum[i]!=0)
        fsum[i]-=10;
 }
       for(k=0;k<sizeof(fsum);k++){
          printf("%s %d",codes[k],fsum[k]);
      }

return 0;
}
```

The Code now crashes after taking the first UPC code as input.

Comment: Yes, msum is a array name

Comment: `scanf("%s",codes[i]);` : `codes[i]` isn't point to allocated memory.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
fsum[i]=((msum+sum2)%10);
```

to

```
fsum[i]=((msum[i]+sum2)%10);
```

That is because `msum` is an array of integers, and `msum[i]` is an integer. As `msum` is an array, it is of type `int*` and is not compatible with `int` for the binary operator `%`

Comment: Yeah, I got that but can you explain me why it crashes after taking the first UPC code.

Comment: @pradyumnarahul I am really sorry, to tell you that it is a separate question as it is unrelated to your question and you will have to ask a new question. If you think this answer has solved your present question do accept this as the answer so that the larger community comes to know that this question has been answered. Sorry once again.

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
char *codes[n];
```

is array of `n` pointers and you don't allocate memory for these pointers and try to scan values to this location so you see a crash

Comment: So what do you suggest to do.

Comment: @pradyumnarahul suggest use `int codes[n][11];` or ``int codes[n][12];``

Comment: @pradyumnarahul because you have more errors. i have post sample.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int checkdigit(int data[12]){
    int i, even, odd, result;

    even = odd = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < 11; ++i){
        if(i & 1)
            even += data[i];
        else
            odd += data[i];
    }
    result = (odd * 3 + even) % 10;
    if(result)
        result = 10 - result;
    return data[11] = result;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int codes[n][12];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 11; ++j){
            scanf("%d", &codes[i][j]);
        }
        checkdigit(codes[i]);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        for(j = 0; j < 12; ++j){
            if(j) putchar(' ');
            printf("%d", codes[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does if(i & 1) mean

Comment: `if(i % 2 == 1)` mean digit even-numberd position.

Comment: Thanks, if I have any further questions I'll fall back on you.